# Any data on complexity of Underscore.js algorithms

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, time-complexity

I cannot find any data on complexity of `underscore`'s functions, at least nothing can be found on the official Underscore.js site; internet search is also empty. Are there any useful hints short of plodding through the source code?

P.S. Would be nice (but not necessary at the moment) to have such info for other node.js libraries.

P.P.S. Thanks to @generalhenry, a drop-in replacement has been found (`lo-dash`). Although it seems to be faster, details of its asymptotic complexity (and that of `underscore`) remain unknown.

Comment: If you're concerned with underscore's performance, you should check out http://lodash.com/ it's a drop in replacement focused on performance.

Comment: Thanks, `npm install lodash` - done. The benchmarks (http://lodash.com/benchmarks), while showing drastic difference in speed for fixed input size, cannot say anything about complexity and scaling performance, though.

Comment: Just curious, could you explain what you mean by 'complexity' and what metrics of complexity you want to judge?

Comment: Asymptotic performance of the algorithm as input size grows to infinity. Am working with middle-size sets (several million records) at the moment (and evaluating different libraries in node.js for suitability), but the situation will definitely become much much worse in the future. Hence the worry.

Comment: underscore is open source, so anyone who understands algorithmic complexity can look at the code and evaluate it for him/herself. If anything is questionable, it can easily be benchmarked to see how it scales. If you're not willing to do that work, then underscore's time complexity isn't really as important to you as you think it is. Sorry to be so blunt, but you do need to follow the principles outlined in http://whathaveyoutried.com/.

Comment: You are right. And yet I was hoping to avoid reinventing the bicycle; if anybody anywhere has done that once, there's no reason to do it again (other than to test for the impact of changed environment).

Comment: As a side note: the lodash benchmarks page compares lodash to underscore.
http://lodash.com/benchmarks